# 32-bit mac apps in the future

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit

It's long been telegraphed that 32-bit apps will no longer work in upcoming versions of macOS. This is rather annoying, because my go-to games when I want to waste 15 minutes are all 32-bit from companies that no longer exist.

Does anyone have any ideas whether there will be any way to run these apps, perhaps in a wrapper? No, booting another OS is not a solution. Is there any info on this issue at all?

Comment: You could use a virtual machine running an old version of macos

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/) or [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) to run older macOS versions. The virtualization runs on top of Catalina so there won‘t be a need to reboot. And unless your games are very GPU-intensive you should get decent performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) My plan is to simply run old versions of the operating system, supported by disk clones made using tools like Carbon Copy Cloner. I currently keep an os 10.9 system running this way, and a 10.14 system in a dual boot capability presently. Perhaps in future I will have a triple boot setup, not looking forward to that.

2) Time machine does not like to restore to an older os version so I use both Time Machine in conjunction with a hot-spare disk clone. Rsync is also able to maintain the freshness of these backups if Carbon Copy Cloner not suitable.

3) I can't see why it wouldn't be possible to convert 32-bit x86 machine code into super ugly 64-bit x86 machine code. After all, doesn't the x64 support 32-bit multiply? Sure it does! A processor supporting x86-64 still powers on in real mode for full backward compatibility, as x86 processors have done since the 80286. x86_64  introduces two new modes of operation, 64-bit mode and compatibility mode, along with a new 4-level paging mode. A chip series called Itanium was invented to attempt at a pure 64 bit architecture. In January 2019, Intel announced that Itanium 3 would be discontinued, with a last order date of January 2020.

Comment: 32bit vs 64bit involves much more than multiplications, even on CPU level. And Apple dropped support for several frameworks/libraries with Catalina so even if you could get the code to run as such you still would lack the environment to run it in.

Comment: The OP states "No, booting another OS is not a solution.", which means he is currently looking for a way to run 32-bit apps on macOS Catalina not boot another OS as you point 1 suggests. What's 2 got to do with the question asked? 3 is covered in the other comment.